# Rich UI capabilities of ESB

Tags: nservicebus, esb, masstransit, rhino-esb

We considering various opensource ESBs such as Mass transit,Rhino ESB,Apache Synapse and NserviceBus etc.Can some one share the UI capabilties of these service busses? Are these ESBs have graphical User interfaces? or which of these ESBs is provides much UI capabilities?

Comment: What kind of UI are you looking for? What would you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

NServiceBus has a suite of tooling to accompany that may meet your needs.  Please see this [link](http://particular.net/service-platform) for more information.

Comment: Yes, there is a UI for designing an NServiceBus-based system integrated into Visual Studio, another UI for production monitoring, and a 3rd which shows in-depth message-flows and saga data changes over time.